# Java - how to charge interest on top of interest

Tags: java

So I'm writing a program for an invoice calculator for class.

However, I need to code interest for every 30 days for 10%

total * interest rate (0.10) if 30 days

So, lets say they need to pay interest for 60 days. so twice

total * interest rate --> with another interest on top of that and so on

another example:
so for the program it depends on the date since last invoice. if it is 30 daysyou will be charged 10% interest. if it is 60 days you will be charged another 10% interest on top of that. if it is 90 days you will be charged another 10% interest on top of that. and so on

Do I use a for loop?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
     Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

     double purchase, invoiceAmount, tax, interest, total = 0;
     int validYear, validMonth, validDay, invoiceYear, invoiceMonth, invoiceDay; 
     int daysdiff;
/*   double invoiceAmount = 0;
     double tax = 0;
     double total = 0;*/


     System.out.println("Welcome to the Invoice Calculator\n");


     System.out.print("Enter the number of minutes you wish to purchase: ");
        purchase = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Today's Date");

        System.out.print ("Year: ");
        validYear = input.nextInt ();

        while(validYear < 1950 || validYear > 2016){

            System.out.print ("Invalid!!\nEnter Year: " );
            validYear = input.nextInt();            
        }       


        System.out.print ("Month: ");
        validMonth = input.nextInt ();


        while(validMonth < 1 || validMonth > 12){

            System.out.print ("Invalid!!\nEnter Month: " );
            validMonth = input.nextInt();           
        }       

        System.out.print ("Day: ");
        validDay = input.nextInt ();


        while(validDay < 1 || validDay > 30){

            System.out.print ("Invalid!!\nEnter day: " );
            validDay = input.nextInt();         
        }       


        System.out.println("Invoice Date");

        System.out.print ("Year: ");
        invoiceYear = input.nextInt ();


        while(validYear < 1950 || validYear > 2016){

            System.out.print ("Invalid!!\nEnter year " );
            invoiceYear = input.nextInt();          
        }       

        System.out.print ("Month: ");
        invoiceMonth = input.nextInt ();


        while(invoiceMonth < 1 || invoiceMonth > 12){

            System.out.print ("Invalid!!\nEnter month: " );
            invoiceMonth = input.nextInt();         
        }       

        System.out.print ("Day: ");
        invoiceDay = input.nextInt ();

        while(invoiceDay < 1 || invoiceDay > 30){

            System.out.print ("Invalid!!\nEnter day: " );
            invoiceDay = input.nextInt();           
        }       






     System.out.println("\nToday's Date is: " + validYear + "/" + validMonth + "/" + validDay);
     System.out.println("Invoice Date is: " + invoiceYear + "/" + invoiceMonth + "/" + invoiceDay + "\n");

     invoiceAmount = (purchase * 0.02) +5;
     tax = (invoiceAmount * 0.13);
     total = (invoiceAmount + tax);
     interest = (total * 0.10);

     // The number of days since invoice date: 

     daysdiff = (validYear - invoiceYear) *365 + (validMonth - invoiceMonth) *30 +(validDay - invoiceDay);


     System.out.print("The number of days since invoice date is: " + daysdiff);

     System.out.print("\nInvoice Amount: $");
     System.out.println(formatter.format(invoiceAmount));

     System.out.print("Tax           : $");
     System.out.println(formatter.format(tax));

     System.out.print("Interest      : $");
     System.out.println(formatter.format(interest));

     System.out.print("TOTAL         : $");
     System.out.println(formatter.format(total));





}
```

}

Thank you

Comment: please show what you have achieved so far

Comment: At least try before you ask on SO

Comment: Added what I have so far

Comment: Please note that the interest to charge is not 10% every 30 days, but (0.10/12). (The 12 is for 12 times per year, 30 days per month, 12 months per year. Approximately.) And, yes, you need a loop for the number of months to charge the interest. Aah. I just read your edit. But keep the (0.10/30) in mind.

Comment: so for the program it depends on the date since last invoice. if it is 30 you will be charged 10% interest. if it is 60 you will be charged another 10% interest on top of that. if it is 90 days you will be charged another 10% interest on top of that. and so on

Comment: Heck, this question has no relevance to java. It is about a trivial algorithm, which is language independent. I wish the "java" shown above was never taught nor produced and instead one first learned about designing code (independently of the language), separating concerns and finally formulating questions. Harsh, but really just a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to tax 10% for every 30days you'd need something like this.

```
public class test {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    double total = 100.0;
    int numDays = 90;

    //gets how many times your invoice days goes into 30
    int taxNum = numDays / 30;
    //decreases total according to your tax
    for( int i = 0; i < taxNum; i++ ){
        total -= total * .1;
    }
    System.out.println(total);
    }
}
```

Comment: you have added code i will take another look at the question

Comment: okay thank you. ive added another explanation on what i needed help with

Comment: Sorry, I'm really new to Java, so how would I print that out?

Comment: i added a print statement

Comment: oh i did the same thing but i put it in between the {} so it wasnt showing. It just shows me 0.0 when printed

Comment: total should be a double

Comment: i got it, but now it says 10.0

Comment: oh wait i think i got it to work. let me test it some more

Comment: I get 2.94 instead of 2.60

Comment: yes. changed it a bit and i get 30.0 only some of the vars

Comment: i can't help you with what you've changed. But that formula works for each iteration of a loop when calculating tax interest

Comment: the only vars i changed were the var names. instead of total i did TotalNum

Comment: running this program copied and pasted i get the output of 72.9

Comment: Alright, well thank you so much for the help. I'll manage and try to find what I did wrong and what I can change. I really appreciate it. I'll work more on int tomorrow.